# Speed of large amount of animated bitmaps in EaselJS

Tags: performance, bitmap, easeljs, animated

I seem to have a bit of trouble with using a large amount of animated bitmaps (all based on the same spritesheet) when using EaselJS. When I run a couple of these at once on my stage, there is no problem at all, but when running a higher amount of them at the same time (starting at around 30 to 40) whilst moving them around I start to have them "flicker" quite a bit, even at an fps of around 10.

I'm not using any shadows or anything else along those lines. Just using animated bitmaps and moving them around.

Does anyone have any good advice around increasing this performance?

Answer (score 11):

Without seeing your code it's hard to know exactly where the bottleneck is. But here are a few places to start looking (starting with the more trivial fixes):

1. Make sure you are using a modern browser. **In the very least, check across a few other browsers/platforms to see if that has any significant change in performance**. From what I understand, EaselJS performance is significantly worse on non-hardware accelerated canvas implementations.
2. **If you can, use createJS's version of TweenJS over other tweening libraries**. TweenJS will tie itself to EaselJS's `Ticker` class, which is more efficient.
3. **Do not call `stage.update()` unless absolutely necessary.** Since `stage.update()` is such an expensive call, you should be as stingy as possible. In fact, you shouldn't really call it at all if you are using the Ticker to regularly update the stage.
4. **Cache wisely and aggressively.** If you have complex static elements on the stage, caching them will save some cycles. However, there is an overhead to caching so save it for containers with a lot of static elements or complexly drawn shapes.
5. **Lower the frequency that EaselJS checks for mouseovers.** If you have enabled mouse over on the stage, pass in a lower frequency ([documentation](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/Stage.html#method_enableMouseOver)). If you don't need it (if you are only listening to clicks), don't enable it at all. Monitoring mouse overs is pretty dang expensive, especially if you have plenty of elements on stage.
6. **Set `stage.snapToPixelsEnabled` to true.** This may or may not help. Theoretically, rendering bitmaps on whole pixels is much more efficient, however this may cause some animations to become jagged and I haven't played around with it enough to know what the other pros and cons are.

I was able to get decent performance with around 600-800 spritesheets at 30FPS and basic tweening using Chrome on a 4 year old iMac (just a quick test).

Answer (score 0):

try using several `Stage` objects at the same time.

Comment: Didn't really speed up performance, since it still has to draw the same amount of animated Sprites at the same time

Comment: did you use different canvas elements for each Stage too?